# How to resolve these debug error Cannot Find local variable extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

Cannot find local variable 'extras'[image]

Comment: Please paste relevant code here.

Comment: Adapter method Call to second Activity                                                        
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewEduActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(FILE_NAME,Path);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

In this error remove the bundle object and pass it is
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

PATH = extras.getString(FILE_NAME);

and Enter this Line

String PATH = getIntent().getStringExtra(FILE_NAME);

to remove this error